# Send an email if grep has results

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, grep

I'm trying to do a simple script that if the "grep" comes with results, send the email with the results. But I want also to send an email if there is a case when there are no rejects

```
#! /bin/bash

FILE=$(find . /opt/FIXLOGS/l51prdsrv* -iname "TRADX_*.log" -type f -exec grep -F 103=16 {} /dev/null \; )>> Rejects.txt

if [ "$FILE" == true ]
then
    mailx -s "Logs $(date +%d-%m-%y)" "email" < Rejects.txt
    rm -f Rejects.txt
elif [ "$FILE" == null ]
then 
    echo "No Rejects" >> Rejects.txt
    mailx -s "Logs $(date +%d-%m-%y)" "email" < Rejects.txt
    rm -f Rejects.txt
fi
```

Comment: Please format your code using code blocks.

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: Thanks just re-order it as the page indicated, thanks for that. Still doesn't work, i believe i'm doing something wrong in the statement

Comment: `true` and `null` don't really have the meaning you expect them to in shell scripts. What exactly is it that you want to check with `if [ "$FILE" == true ]`?

Comment: That could be what is wrong, i'm not sure on what to put as a condition, since i want to check if the grep does find the tag 103=16 send the email with the results. And if it does not find anything, send an email with "No Rejects" in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, everything is pretty much just a string. `null` is a string, not a null reference like in other languages. `true` is also a string (unless it's the *command* `true`, but that's not the case in your comparison).

If you want to test that a file exists, you'd use `[[ -f "$FILE" ]]`. However, the file is going to exist in your case even if `grep` matches nothing because bash automatically creates the file when you set it as the destination for your output. What you really need is `-s` which tests if the file exists and has size greater than 0.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . /opt/FIXLOGS/l51prdsrv* -iname "TRADX_*.log" -type f -exec grep -F 103=16 {} /dev/null \; >> Rejects.txt

if [[ -s Rejects.txt ]] ; then
 : # grep wrote stuff into the file
else
 : # file is empty so grep found nothing
fi
```